# Pillow won't open an image in the same directory. "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:"

Tags: python, image, python-3.9

The pillow library won't open an image in the same directory as the script anymore, while it used to. I haven't changed anything to do with how the file is loaded. I of course have the jpg in the folder with the script while I'm testing it.

I've tried the import to all three of these since I've read that works:

```
from PIL import Image
```

```
import PIL.Image
```

```
import PIL
```

None of these have worked and the output is

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pic.jpg'
```

The code loading the image is:

```
def main(new_width=300):
    
    try:
        image = PIL.Image.open("pic.jpg")
    except:
        print("Please rename the file to 'pic.jpg' and restart the script")
        quit()
```

Comment: "I of course have the jpg in the folder with the script while I'm testing it." Okay, and why are you expecting the script to look in that folder? Do you know what a *current working directory* is? Do you know how to check it? Did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the absolute path to the image

```
from PIL import Image

try:
    image = Image.open("/path/to/pic.jpg")
except:
    print("Please rename the file to 'pic.jpg' and restart the script")
    quit()
```

Comment: I tried that and it worked then I went back to the way I was doing it before and it works... So I don't know what's up with it. I want to implement a way for you to put the path Into it by using input but when I tried that before it also errored the same way. Ever since I've been tinkering with it it seems sperratic. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JerebGainer if you have problem with path ask another question as it seems not PIL related